# Python microservice for Elastic logic

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask, architecture, microservices

I want to implement Python Flask microservice for serving Elasticsearch queries.

Before I dive in, I would like to know some pros and cons of approaches I can take.

1. Send passive cURL requests and get responses.
2. Have active session in something like elasticsearch-py.

I would like to hear some advice on which approach is in your experience more reliable, safe or simple to maintain. Flask service and Elastic will not be on the same server, so there might be interesting M-to-N mapping with active sessions between servers.